# Trigger function on page change jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a function each time user changes 'page'in jQuery Mobile.

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```

Doesn't work because all the pages are contained in the same .html.
The only way i can get it to work is if i listen on the nav buttons like this

```
$('#navNext').click(function() {
retrieveSession();
});
```

This causes a whole lot of head aches so i tried this

```
function retrieveSession(){ 

    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;


    $( "#" + activePageId ).on( "pagechange", function() {
        if (activePageId === "q1"){                                
                alert("q1");

            } else if (activePageId === "q2"){              
                alert("q2");

            } else if (activePageId === "q3"){              
                alert("q3");    

            } else if (activePageId === "q4"){              
                alert("q4");
            }; 
    });
}
```

Then i run the function in  $(document).ready(function(){}, the app still runs fine, but no alert when navigating through the 'pages'.
No exceptions either.
I have searched on here and can only find vague connections through other questions that don't help me with a solution.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you run this `$('#navNext').length` on chrome console after page load, if it more than 1 the event will be associated with the first element, try to use class rather than id, if it is in the same html page.

Comment: There is only one next button, I made the back and next buttons persistent so i could have only one of each.

Comment: Comes back 0, maybe because the footer/nav is out side the body? The id is there and the button works when i set it with the function, it causes a feed back loop with another function though.

Comment: My mistake i am using .class*

Comment: Can you debug your js in chrome and find which line is failing or misbehaving..